# How to use pdf.js with RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, magento2, amd, pdf.js

I'm trying implementing the [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) in Magento2 which use RequireJS, how could I implement it since the global var below has not been accessible?

```
// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
```

[image: pdf.js + requirejs]

Answer (score 0):

To implement it with RequireJS you must use the names to instantiate like this image below.
As you can see you can change the global var using the local `pdfjsLib` created by the clojure.

[image: requirejs-config file]
[image: pdf.js amd]

Reference: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7287#issuecomment-348143963

Answer (score 0):

This is really helpful.
If you are using oracle JET. You also need to specify these entries in path_mapping.json and viewmodel. You can't rename it to pdf or something else... Stick to this long name. It will work.

```
    "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf": {
  "cwd": "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build",
  "debug": {
    "src":  "pdf.js",
    "path": "libs/pdfjs/dist/pdf.js"
  },
  "release": {
    "src": "pdf.min.js",
    "path": "libs/pdfjs/dist/pdf.min.js"
  }
},

"pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker": {
  "cwd": "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build",
  "debug": {
    "src":  "pdf.worker.js",
    "path": "libs/pdfjs/dist/pdf.worker.js"
  },
  "release": {
    "src": "pdf.worker.min.js",
    "path": "libs/pdfjs/dist/pdf.worker.min.js"
  }
},
```

// The below code should appear in your viewmodel js

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = FRONTEND_HOST + "/js/libs/pdfjs/dist/pdf.worker.js";
```